# Cannot connect to Azure SQL database from Docker container running ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL database from a Docker container running an ASP.NET Core application on my localhost.

When I run the application locally, through IIS Express, all works well. The connection with the Azure SQL database can be made if I add the client IP to the Azure SQL Server firewall.

The logs clearly indicate an issue with the database connectivity, but I cannot fathom what the solution might be. When I run the container through  `docker run -it -d -p 8080:80 myorg/myapp:mytag`, `docker inspect` gives me the following information:

```json
{
   "EventId":20004,
   "LogLevel":"Error",
   "Category":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection",
   "Message":"An error occurred using the connection to database \u0027mydb\u0027 on server \u0027tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net,1433\u0027.",
   "State":{
      "Message":"An error occurred using the connection to database \u0027mydb\u0027 on server \u0027tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net,1433\u0027.",
      "database":"mydb",
      "server":"tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net,1433",
      "{OriginalFormat}":"An error occurred using the connection to database \\u0}\u0027 on server \u0027{server}\u0027."
   }
}
```

The Dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY "./Nuget.config" ./
COPY ["MyAppMobile.Backend/nuget.config", "MyAppMobile.Backend/"]
COPY ["MyAppMobile.Backend/MyAppMobile.Backend.csproj", "MyAppMobile.Backend/"]
COPY ["MyAppEF.NETCore/MyAppEF.NETCore.csproj", "MyAppEF.NETCore/"]
COPY ["MyAppCore.NETCore/MyAppCore.NETCore.csproj", "MyAppCore.NETCore/"]
COPY ["MyAppSql/MyAppSql.csproj", "MyAppSql/"]
COPY ["MyAppMachine/MyAppMachine.csproj", "MyAppMachine/"]

RUN dotnet restore  --configfile Nuget.config "MyAppMobile.Backend/MyAppMobile.Backend.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyAppMobile.Backend"
RUN dotnet build "MyAppMobile.Backend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAppMobile.Backend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAppMobile.Backend.dll"]
```

I tried to add the container's IP Address via the `docker inspect 6c3cac723a3c | findstr "IPAddress"` command to the accepted IP addresses in the firewall, to no avail. Same results when I add the container's network IP to the firewall list.

Any idea what should be done to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to allow the IP address of your local machine?

Comment: Yes, I have. Same result.

Comment: The address returned from `docker inspect 6c3cac723a3c | findstr "IPAddress"` is likely a non-routable address (for local networking only). Similarly your machine's IP address is likely the same. If you visit [ipchicken.com](https://ipchicken.com/) in a web browser to view your public IP address, as seen from the public internet, what happens when you add that address to the firewall?

Comment: As far as I know, that's what the Add Client IP button does in the Azure Portal. I've done that but it still doesn't connect to the database.